# 2 override ToString() methods across multiple classes

Tags: c#

This is what my code looks like:

```
public class Inventory 
{

    private List<Item> list = new List<Item>();

    public List<Item> list { get; set; }

    public Inventory()
    {
        list = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item("iPod"),
            new Item("Motorolla"),
            new Item("Samsung"),
            new Item("Nokia")
        };
    }

    public override String ToString() 
    {
        String stuff = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Item items = list[i];
            stuff += items.ToString();
        }

        return name + stuff;
    }
}
```

This is my Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public override String ToString() => ProductCost().ToString();
}
```

Under my Form.cs:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var products = new Inventory();
    lstBox.Items.Add(products);     // Display products     
}
```

My problem is instead of returning `"name + stuff"`, it returns the "ProductCost" which I'm puzzled over since I have initialized an Inventory object - shouldn't it be calling the overridden `ToString()` method in `Inventory` instead of what I have in Item.cs?

Note: I need to have both `ToString()` implemented so no, deleting one of them isn't gonna fly unfortunately.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking - when you say "it returns" what is "it"? Is the program running and showing a list box is with the item name "ProductCost"? Also, it doesn't look like you've posted all the relevant code - what is `name` in `Inventory.ToString()`?

Comment: Yes, it displays the Product Cost in the listbox but what I was hoping for is really just the name + products (List<>) in it. The name its returning is the store name so right off the bat, I can easily tell that its not returning the ToString() method I made in my Inventory.cs

Comment: The code examples here a bit incomplete.  Is `name` a property/field of the `Inventory` class?  Also, what does `ProductCost().ToString()` do?  It seems you have three `ToString()` methods but are only providing examples for two of them.

Comment: Name has its own Public property to give access and ProductCost() just calculates the product * tax and to my knowledge I have only made 2 ToString() methods which is separated - one in Item.cs and another in Inventory.cs

Comment: @iStudent But what do you mean "it returns"? Do you mean `Item.ToString`, or `Inventory.ToString`? Which one is giving you the issue? Also, I have no idea why you think the two independent `ToString` methods are interferring

Comment: Also, `Item items` should be called `Item item` instead. It just confused me for a second because I thought you were using an `IEnumerable.ToString`

Comment: @iStudent Could you provide an example of what you expect the resulting string to look like?

Comment: So, when you say it's returning `ProductCost`, is it returning the product cost of one `Item`, two `Item`s, or all of them? If it's the product cost of one of the items, which one? The first in the list, last in the list?

Comment: It return the Item.ToString instead of Inventory.ToString. Just to clarify the listbox should display "Store name, Ipod, Motorolla, Samsung, Nokia" however it displays its Product Cost which is in the Item.ToString() thats why I think they are interferring.

Comment: The `Inventory.ToString()` method is explicitly calling the `Item.ToString()` method for each item in the list.  Maybe instead of doing `stuff += items.ToString();` you should be doing `stuff += items.name;` (or whatever the name field is called).  Also, you may want to format the string with commas and spacing.

Comment: Yep that worked but now its showing as "IpodMotorollaSamsungNokia". As you said, there needs to be a format in there. Thanks, appreciate your help humbleice

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but it may make sense to change the `Item.ToString()` method to return the `name` value and display `ProductCost()` some other way.  `name` seems more appropriate for the `ToString()` value of an Item than it's cost.

Comment: Side note, you're supposed to use `string` not `String`, unless you're getting static methods or properties from the class, and `string` is `null` by default, so you don't have to set it to `null`. In fact, you should be setting it to `""` or `"String.Empty` to avoid a `null reference exception`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning `Item.ToString()` because you're calling it when you do `stuff += items.ToString();`.

Instead, just do:

```
string stuff = "Items: ";

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Item items = list[i];
    stuff += items.Name + ", ";
}

// Remove the last comma
stuff = stuff.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(", "));
return name + stuff;
```

If we don't remove the last comma, we get this:

```
"Items: Ipod, Motorolla, Samsung, Nokia, "
```

Instead of:

```
"Items: Ipod, Motorolla, Samsung, Nokia"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you upvote this answer by clicking on the top arrow pointing up, and accept it as the answer by clicking the checkmark? The up arrow and checkmark are both to the top left of the answer

Comment: you should have a look at string.Join